# Simple Calculated Member Running for Forever - MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am facing very strange issue with MDX (SSAS 2014), on which simplest calculated member is taking forever to execute. Could someone please help me to understand why i am facing this issue. If i not use calculated member everything works fast and result comes in seconds. When i remove Producer attribute, query performances well.

Below is the complete query.

WITH
MEMBER Measures.AsOfDate AS ("[Policy Effective Date].[Year-Month].[Date].&[2018-01-04T00:00:00]")

MEMBER Measures.YTDPremium AS AGGREGATE (YTD(STRTOMEMBER(Measures.AsOfDate)), [Measures].[Written Premium]) 
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{ 
Measures.YTDPremium

} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY 
{ 
( 
[Program].[Program Name].[Program Name]

,[Insuring Company].[Insuring Company Name].[Insuring Company Name]

,[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business]

,[Producer].[Producer Name].[Producer Name]

) 
} ON ROWS 
FROM [Premium]

Answer (score 0):

Try understand what the following part does in your query

> NON EMPTY { ( [Program].[Program Name].[Program Name]
>
> ,[Insuring Company].[Insuring Company Name].[Insuring Company Name]
>
> ,[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business]
>
> ,[Producer].[Producer Name].[Producer Name]
>
> ) } ON ROWS

In the above MDX you are telling the server to take a cross product of all values of "Programs", "Line Of Business" and "Producer Name". So lets say you have 4 values of programs , 3 values of line of business and 2 values of producer name. The total combinations are 4*3*2=24

Now the "Non empty" removes any combinations that are not present in your dataset. This is done by removing all rows that have "Null" value in column value.

Your measure is returning value irrespective if that combination exists or not. You can modify your Calculatedmeasure to return value only in the case if the combination is valid. This can be achived by checking an actual measure for that combination

Edit: based the below example is based on the comment

In the below example i am trying to get the internet sales amount categories and components

```
select 
{ [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]  } 
on columns,
(
[Product].[Category].[Category],
[Customer].[Country].[Country]
)
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result 
[image]

Now add "Non empty" to the query and observe the results.

Results
[image]

Now lets add calculted measure that returns "hello". Notice how the non empty clause is ineffective.

[image]

Now modify the code make the calculated measure check other measures for null

```
with member measures.t as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = null then null else "hello" end

select 
{ [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ,measures.t }
on columns,
non empty
(
[Product].[Category].[Category],
[Customer].[Country].[Country]
)
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

Result

[image]

**The bottom line: Because of cross product your result is so huge that SSAS is having hard time handling it.**

Comment: i tried to remove non empty as well, however query still keep on running. How can i modify the query to check the measure value exists ? Could you please provide a mdx example or alter the existing one. It will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: so how to avoid cross product and bring the result quickly. I kept non empty in the query. what is the meaning to keep this line of code "with member measures.t as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = null then null else "hello" end". Any how non empty clause will filter it. Sry i too new to MDX.

Comment: The meaning of the above line is to return "hello" only when you have a value for [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]. Does it make sense?

Comment: But by adding that is not making any difference in my query performance. Whats your advice to tune the provided query so that it can bring the result at least. Currently it just keep running.

Comment: I need to see your query?

Comment: WITH MEMBER Measures.AsOfDate AS ("[Policy Effective Date].[Year-Month].[Date].&[2018-01-04T00:00:00]")

MEMBER Measures.YTDPremium AS AGGREGATE (YTD(STRTOMEMBER(Measures.AsOfDate)), [Measures].[Written Premium]) SELECT NON EMPTY { Measures.YTDPremium

} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { ( [Program].[Program Name].[Program Name]

,[Insuring Company].[Insuring Company Name].[Insuring Company Name]

,[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business]

,[Producer].[Producer Name].[Producer Name]

) } ON ROWS FROM [Premium]

Comment: WITH MEMBER Measures.AsOfDate AS ("[Policy Effective Date].[Year-Month].[Date].&[2018-01-04T00:00:00]") 
MEMBER Measures.YTDPremium AS case when [Measures].[Written Premium] = null then null else  AGGREGATE (YTD(STRTOMEMBER(Measures.AsOfDate)), [Measures].[Written Premium]) end
SELECT NON EMPTY { Measures.YTDPremium } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { (
 [Program].[Program Name].[Program Name] ,
 [Insuring Company].[Insuring Company Name].[Insuring Company Name] ,
[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business].[Line Of Business] ,
[Producer].[Producer Name].[Producer Name] ) } ON ROWS FROM [Premium]

Comment: It did work thanks alot for help. Do you refer any book/link/video/blog on MDX? Thanks again..

Comment: Your are welcome. You should mark it as answer or/upvote it based on how helpful it was. I do refer a book will add the name here later